# Проблема с русскими символами в jsoup

Tags: java, android, url, jsoup

Делаю вот там

```
 final String url = "https://yandex.com/images/search?text=";
        final String charset = "utf-8";
        try {
            String wordParam = URLEncoder.encode(strings[0], charset);
            Document docImage = Jsoup.connect(url + wordParam+"&isize=large").get();
            Elements images = docImage.select("img.serp-item__thumb");
            Elements links = docImage.select("div.serp-item");
```

Если strings[0] состоит из русских символов, то результат выдаёт какую-то ерунду. Если же полученный URL скопировать в браузер, то всё ок. Опытным путём установил, что в случае русских символов в начало каждого символа добавляется %2525. Что делать?

Comment: А если не кодировать `wordParam` - очень похоже что `Jsoup` сам это делает.

Comment: Хотя у Вас даже тройная кодировка - то есть строка уже до этого кода была закодирована.

Comment: пробовал не кодировать, то же самое.

Comment: Выведите в лог `strings[0]` в этом месте, если он "не русский" смотрите по коду где он мог быть кодирован раньше

Comment: Стоп, %2525 у Вас в запросе или ответе?

Comment: у меня %2525 в docImage уже, там есть поле, в которое пишется, какой запрос был выполнен. А до запроса всё нормально. url + wordParam+"&isize=large" - идёт без %2525

Comment: Похоже это Ваш случай: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43426676

Comment: Попробуйте заменить yandex.com на yandex.ru - редирект должен отпасть и проблема вместе с ним.

Comment: спасибо, попробую

Comment: не помогло, ничего не изменилось

Comment: хотя нет, стало просто %25, но всё равно не работает

Comment: нужно было убрать encode и сделать yandex.ru. Теперь всё работает, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно было убрать encode и сделать yandex.ru

Answer (score 0):

Типичная ошибка в такого рода изысканиях состоит в том, что когда вы задаете русский текст в самом исходнике, то кодировка русского текста совпадает с кодировкой самих исходников. Вообще рекомендуемая кодировка исходников это *UTF-8* (для Android это вообще обязательное требование) - настройка кодировки исходников зависит от IDE, в котором вы работаете. Для Android Studio это задается так:

*File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings->File Encodings->change Project Encoding->UTF-8*

Поэтому ваш перл:

> Если strings[0] состоит из русских символов, то результат выдаёт какую-то ерунду.

не имеет смысла, без указания кодировки русских символов.

Comment: File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings->File Encodings->change Project Encoding->UTF-8

Всё так и установлено
И русский текст у меня не задаётся в исходниках, а вводится в EditText